# Example of a Contractive mapping which is not a contraction mapping.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Can anyone please provide me an example of a **Contractive mapping** which is not a **Contraction mapping.**

Definitions:

> A mapping $T: M\to M$ is said to be **contractive** if $d(Tx, Ty)<d(x,y)$ for each $x,y\in M$ with $x\neq y,$
>
> A mapping $T: M\to M$ is said to be **contraction** if there exist a constant $0\leq k<1$ such that $d(Tx, Ty)\leq k d(x,y)$ for each $x,y\in M$ with $x\neq y,$

Comment: Hint: cook up something with help of mean value theorem.

Comment: $M=[0,{\pi \over 2}), T = \sin$.

Comment: On $\mathbb R$, $x-\arctan(x)$ works.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Or just $\arctan$?

Comment: @copper.hat: Oh yeah, but for what it's worth $x-\arctan(x)+2$ would also give a contractive bijection of $\mathbb R$ without fixed points.

Comment: The following link is to a related question, because each example there is also an example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/88784/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$    \frac{3x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}{4}   $$
is a bijection of the real line with no fixpoint. The bit about contraction is the Mean Value Theorem together with the observation that the derivative is always between $0$ and $1,$ while getting arbitrarily close to $1$ as $x$ goes to $+ \infty$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up in case you care: I believe we can read most of your email address in one of those tabs.

Comment: @Glitch thanks, it's alright. I make it visible in my profile. I do get some email I don't like from time to time (related to this site) but never by a bot.

Comment: @WillJagy, Thank you, for answering the question with such a great explanation. I get your point, we can take any function whose derivative approaches to $1$ on the given domain.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one :

Let $f(x)=\sqrt x$ be defined on $D= (\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Now $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|=\frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}<|x-y|$ so that $f$ is contractive. If possible let $f$ be contraction i.e. $\exists\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<1$ such that $\forall x,y\in D$ we have $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|\leq\alpha|x-y|$

or $1\leq\alpha|\sqrt x+\sqrt y|$ or $\alpha\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}$ for all $x,y\in D$.

Now given any $\beta<1$ we can find $x_{\beta},y_{\beta}\in D$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt x_{\beta}+\sqrt y_{\beta}}>\beta$ so that $\alpha>\beta$. Which means we must have $\alpha\geq 1$; a contradiction.